# How to add appium server in eclipse workspace

Tags: java, node.js, eclipse, appium

I have requirement like i don't want to install appium in my machine with the help of (npm install -g appium) So i want to run appium commands in command line mode with the help of node-modules. So in this consideration how can i add this into my eclipse project. I am looking exact like selendroid server jar configuration Does we have this kind of flexibility with appium.

As simple as i am looking every thing(Appium server should start from eclipse work space) should be in my eclipse project only for all platforms(Linux, win, mac).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any one have any idea on this

Comment: if any one have to look this issue. Given a solution is very appreciated.